# Access to refs in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I pass ref in two same components like this:

```
:ref="'flipGroupModal' + item.id"
```

for access to unique.

I want to have always the same log ( 2nd image )

When I console.log(this.$refs) One time I have this:

[image: refs]

and in another component I have this:

[image: refs2]

can you help me.

Comment: where do you log it? which hook

Comment: I log it in my function , when I open the component modal

Comment: please share more code and give more details

Comment: well you should log it in mounted hook in model component

Comment: I log in because i make a change in function on  this.$refs.modal123456.loading = true,
So I need this here

Comment: I just wanna know why on on request I have a direct access to ref an the other request, I have an array ?